# plotting legends in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

How do you plot legends for functions without using the PlotLegends package?

Comment: What specifically is wrong with PlotLegends? I mean, you can do legends without it (see my answer) but it is kludgy at best.

Comment: @Timo I'm sorry to say, but the legends are kinda ugly. A huge box, with the content widely spaced. A drop shadow by default that no one uses. Numerous artefacts, like illustrated below (but there are more).

Comment: @Sjoerd: Don't be sorry, I agree that they are ugly. But that was probably not the reason why the OP posted this question, hence my asking for what specifically (s)he has a problem with.

Answer (score 15):

I, too, was disappointed by the difficulty of getting PlotLegend to work correctly.  I wrote my own brief function to make my own custom figure legends:

```
makePlotLegend[names_, markers_, origin_, markerSize_, fontSize_, font_] := 
  Join @@ Table[{
    Text[
      Style[names[[i]], FontSize -> fontSize, font], 
      Offset[
        {1.5*markerSize, -(i - 0.5) * Max[markerSize,fontSize] * 1.25},
        Scaled[origin]
      ],
      {-1, 0}
    ],
    Inset[
      Show[markers[[i]], ImageSize -> markerSize],
      Offset[
        {0.5*markerSize, -(i - 0.5) * Max[markerSize,fontSize] * 1.25},
        Scaled[origin]
      ],
      {0, 0}, 
      Background -> Directive[Opacity[0], White]
    ]
  },
  {i, 1, Length[names]}
];
```

It is flexible, but not so easy to use.  "names" is a list of strings to render in the legend; "markers" is a list with the same length as "names" of Graphics objects representing the plot markers or graphics to render; "origin" is a two-element list with the absolute horizontal and vertical position of the upper-left corner of the legend; "markerSize" is the number of points to scale the markers to; "fontSize" is the font size; "font" is the name of the font to use.  Here is an example:

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
  Epilog -> makePlotLegend[
    {x, x^2},
    (Graphics[{#, Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]}]) & /@ {Blue, Red},
    {0.9, 0.3},
    12,
    12,
    "Arial"
  ]
]
```

[image: generated image]

Answer (score 7):

I would also be very interested in an answer to this question.

To tell you what is wrong with PlotLegends: It is terribly unstable and in many instances doesn't work at all.

Here is an example where PlotLegends screws up completely. Output is from Mathematica 7.0:

Assume that we have measured some data points corresponding to a number of functions, and we want to show how well they compare to the ideal function, or maybe how well they match with a calculated fit. No problem! We'll just Show[] the smooth plot together with a ListPlot of the data points, right?

It could look something like this:

```
Show[
 Plot[{Sin[x], Sinh[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}],
 ListPlot[Join[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[-Pi, Pi, .5], 
               {#, Sinh[#]} & /@ Range[-Pi, Pi, .5]]]
 ]
```

[image]

Now we'd like to put a legend on the plot, so readers will know what on earth they're looking at. Easier said than done, mister! Let's add the PlotLegend to the Plot[]:

```
Show[
  Plot[{Sin[x], Sinh[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLegend -> {Sin[x], Sinh[x]}],
  ListPlot[Join[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[-Pi, Pi, .5], 
                {#, Sinh[#]} & /@ Range[-Pi, Pi, .5]]]
 ]
```

[image]

This looks GREAT! Publish immediately!

For such a basic and ubiquitously needed functionality, it sure has been a lot of work to find an alternative to PlotLegend that just works. The best alternative I've found so far has been to meticulously construct a list of plotstyles, then construct the legend by hand, and finally to show it together with the plot using ShowLegend[]. (See for example [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5789281&tstart=0)) It's possible, but a lot of work.

So if anyone knows of a workaround to make PlotLegend work, an alternative package that works better, or just a neat way to get legends that can be automated easily, I would be very grateful! It would certainly make life a little bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing the weird behavior described by James When you are trying to use 'Show' to combine two images, then you should play around with using the 'Overlay' function instead of 'Show'.

Alternatively, I have found that as long as both graphics have a legend then 'Show' will render the composite image correctly.

If it looks a bit silly having two legends then you can remove the one from the second graphic by using options like:

```
PlotLegend -> {},
LegendPosition -> {0.1, 0.1},
LegendSize -> 0.001,
LegendShadow -> None,
LegendBorder -> None
```

This creates an empty and invisible legend but still allows the two graphics to be composed correctly by 'Show'.