# Combining Plots in Mathematica is not giving the expected result

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I'm trying to combine 3 functions graphed on a `Plot[]` and 1 function graphed on a `ParametricPlot[]`. My equations are as follows:

```
plota = Plot[{-2 x, -2 Sqrt[x], -2 x^(3/5)}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegend -> {"-2 x", "-2 \!\(\*SqrtBox[\(x\)]\)", "-2 \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3/5\)]\)"}]
plotb = ParametricPlot[{2.4056 (u - Sin[u]), 2.4056 (Cos[u] - 1)}, {u,0, 1.40138}, PlotLegend -> {"Problem 3"}]
Show[plota, plotb]
```

This is the image it gives:

[image: Combined Graph]

Comment: This is the right place. Your math.se question is in the wrong place. Please delete that. You'll get answers here.

Comment: @yoda: thanks for per-emptively answering one of my questions. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As yoda said, `PlotLegends` is terrible. However, if you don't mind setting the plot styles manually and repeating them lateron, `ShowLegend` can help.

```
 plota = Plot[{-2 x, -2 Sqrt[x], -2 x^(3/5)}, {x, 0, 1}, 
              PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}, {Orange}}];
 plotb = ParametricPlot[{2.4056 (u - Sin[u]), 2.4056 (Cos[u] - 1)}, {u, 0, 1.40138}, 
                        PlotStyle -> {{Black}}];
```

And now

```
ShowLegend[Show[plota, plotb], 
          {{{Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}], Label1},          
            {Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}], Label2},
            {Graphics[{Orange, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}], Label3}, 
            {Graphics[{Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}], Label4}},
           LegendSize -> {0.5, 0.5}, LegendPosition -> {0.5, -0.2}}]
```

which will give you this:

[image]

You can also write some simple functions to make this a little less cumbersome, if you deal with this problem often.

Comment: Oh, wow. I just edited my answer to add the exact same thing, and I see you posted a whole 10 minutes before my edit. I didn't get the notification while I was messing around in the editor, as I had already answered the post. Have a hearty upvote! :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the root cause of the error is the `PlotLegends` package, which is a terrible, buggy package. Removing that, `Show` combines them correctly:

```
plota = Plot[{-2 x, -2 Sqrt[x], -2 x^(3/5)}, {x, 0, 1}]
plotb = ParametricPlot[{2.4056 (u - Sin[u]), 2.4056 (Cos[u] - 1)}, {u,
    0, 1.40138}]
Show[plota, plotb]
```

[image]

You can see Simon's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221315/how-do-i-label-different-curves-in-mathematica/7221397#7221397) for ideas to label your different curves without using `PlotLegends`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463437/plotting-legends-in-mathematica/3533152#3533152) by James also demonstrates why `PlotLegends` has the reputation it has...

---

You can still salvage something with the `PlotLegends` package. Here's an example using `ShowLegends` that you can modify to your tastes

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Pink};
legends = {-2 x, -2 Sqrt[x], -2 x^(3/5), "Problem 3"};

plota = Plot[{-2 x, -2 Sqrt[x], -2 x^(3/5)}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> colors[[1 ;; 3]]];
plotb = ParametricPlot[{2.4056 (u - Sin[u]), 2.4056 (Cos[u] - 1)}, {u,
     0, 1.40138}, PlotStyle -> colors[[4]]];
ShowLegend[
 Show[plota, 
  plotb], {Table[{Graphics[{colors[[i]], Thick, 
      Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}], legends[[i]]}, {i, 4}], 
  LegendPosition -> {0.4, -0.15}, LegendSpacing -> 0, 
  LegendShadow -> None, LegendSize -> 0.6}]
```

[image]

Comment: I can't use the `fns[x_] :=` notation he is using, because I have a parametric equation. Can you show me how to add labels? Also, I imported an image into my LaTeX document, but it was too big so I scaled it by .5, which made it look pretty crappy. How can I make it smaller and still look nice?

Comment: Do you know of any good alternative package for legends? (Not somethingl like LevelScheme that totally redesigns the graphics system.  Just plain legends.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Sadly, I don't... Because of that, I tend to avoid labeling my curves (at most 3/plot) and instead label them in the figure caption text.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers pointed out, the culprit is `PlotLegend`. So, sometimes is useful to be able to roll your own plot legends:

```
plotStyle = {Red, Green, Blue};
labls = {"a", "b", "Let's go"};
f[i_, s_] := {Graphics[{plotStyle[[i]], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
    ImageSize -> {15, 10}], Style[labls[[i]], s]};

Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> plotStyle,
 Epilog ->
  Inset[Framed[Style@Column[{Grid[Table[f[i, 15], {i, 1, 3}]]}]],
   Offset[{-2, -2}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}],
 PlotRangePadding -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey belisarius, I just realized that your top voted answer has more votes than any of the top voted answers of any of the top 12 all-time SO users.  o_o

Comment: @Mr. Yep. I lost my fortune bribing users :D. It was also the most voted non-CW answer.

Comment: That answer is still reddit material. All belisarius needs to do (or maybe he is, already) is periodically post a link to reddit and title it _"Is rand() more random than rand()*rand()? OMG!! MIND = BLOWN!!!"_ and watch the upvotes trickle in for the next 5 days :P

Comment: @yoda I visited reddit only once, and I am not sure about the mechanics of the site. Could you do that for me? :D